# Adding a shaded box to a plot in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I am looking to add a shaded box to my plot below. I want the box to go from Aug 25-Aug 30 and to run the length of the Y axis.

The following is my code for the two plots I have made...

```
df = pd.read_excel('salinity_temp.xlsx')
dates = df['Date']
sal = df['Salinity']
temp = df['Temperature']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8,8), sharex=True)

axes[0].plot(dates, sal, lw=5, color="red")
axes[0].set_ylabel('Salinity (PSU)')
axes[0].set_title('Salinity', fontsize=14)

axes[1].set_title('Temperature', fontsize=14)
axes[1].plot(dates, temp, lw=5, color="blue")
axes[1].set_ylabel('Temperature (C)')
axes[1].set_xlabel('Dates, 2017', fontsize=12)
axes[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%b %d'))
axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%b %d'))

axes[1].xaxis_date()
axes[0].xaxis_date()
```

I want the shaded box to highlight when Hurricane Harvey hit Houston, Texas (Aug 25- Aug 30). My data looks like:

```
Date    Salinity    Temperature
20-Aug  15.88144647 31.64707184
21-Aug  18.83088846 31.43848419
22-Aug  19.51015264 31.47655487
23-Aug  23.41655369 31.198349
24-Aug  25.16410124 30.63014984
25-Aug  25.2273574  28.8677597
26-Aug  28.35557667 27.49458313
27-Aug  18.52829235 25.92834473
28-Aug  7.423231661 24.06635284
29-Aug  0.520394177 23.47881317
30-Aug  0.238508327 23.90857697
31-Aug  0.143210364 24.30892944
1-Sep   0.206473387 25.20442963
2-Sep   0.241343182 26.32663727
3-Sep   0.58000503  26.93431854
4-Sep   1.182055098 27.8212738
5-Sep   3.632014919 28.23947906
6-Sep   4.672006985 27.29686737
7-Sep   5.938766377 26.8693161
8-Sep   9.107671159 26.48963928
9-Sep   8.180587303 26.05213165
10-Sep  6.200532091 25.73104858
11-Sep  5.144526191 25.60035706
12-Sep  5.106032451 25.73139191
13-Sep  4.279492562 26.06132507
14-Sep  5.255868992 26.74919128
15-Sep  8.026764063 27.23724365
```

I have tried using the rectangle function in this link (https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/how-to-add-a-patch-in-a-plot-in-python/5518) however can't seem to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independent of your specific data, it sounds like you need [`axvspan`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan). Try running this after your plotting code:

```
for ax in axes:
    ax.axvspan('2017-08-25', '2017-08-30', color='black', alpha=0.5)
```

This will work if `dates = df['Date']` is stored as type `datetime64`. It might not work with other datetime data types, and it won't work if `dates` contains date strings.